# remove navigation controller from superview

Tags: ios, swift3

So i have an app were you're supposed to chose a location from a map but the way i'm doing it is by a popup off a view controller that has a MapKit and a search bar and a button for choosing users location, the problem lies on when i'm done with the View I normally called the

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

but the thing that is being remove is the View controller itself but il leaves behind the navigation bar and it doesn't let me do nothing else (in fact when I go to another tab and return to the same one the VC returns).

the way i'm instantiating the VC is like this:

```
func location ()
{
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapV") as! UBICACIONViewController

            let nav1 = UINavigationController()
            nav1.viewControllers = [vc]

            self.addChildViewController(nav1)


            self.view.addSubview(nav1.view)

            vc.delegate = self //this for the info that i'm getting afte(works fine)

            nav1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

So until here works fin but when the user pick te button that says "Use My Location" and tries to return there's the problem.

in my VC view controller this is what happens when finished:

```
func Remove()
{
        if let del = delegate {
            del.dataChanged(str: Event.sharedInstance.Location!)
        }

        self.view.removeFromSuperview() //Problem Here :/
}
```

[Second VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFtPO.png)

[Return to First VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK0yF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have added a child view controller nav1. And nav1 has a subview nav1.view.
while removing you are removing this view from its superview, not the child view controller added.

Any ways, From you screen short..I understand that the pop up view is off full screen then why dont you present this VC modally, or else push it to navigation stack.

Comment: I tought about that, the problem is the user writes some stuff in the UIttextField and in the date picker between other stuff, i was using segue and the info was lost after returning, any idea?

Comment: the content of UItextfield is in 1st view controller..rite?
then the data shouldn't be gone unless you are reseting it while the view appears.